# Assign key to a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object like this

```
{
    "headings": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",

    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            {
                "a": "abc",
                "b": def,
            },
            value1,
            value2,
            value3

        ],
        [
            {
                "a": "abc",
                "b": def,
            },
            value1,
            value2,
            value3

        ],
    ]
}
```

and I would like to convert headings as keys to the object rows like this one

```
{
    "rows": [
        [
            "col1": {
                "a": "abc",
                "b": def,
            },
            "col2": value1,
            "col3": value2,
            "col4": value3

        ],
        [
            "col1": {
                "a": "abc",
                "b": def,
            },
            "col2": value1,
            "col3": value2,
            "col4": value3

        ],
    ]
}
```

I looked at https://lodash.com/ and I did not find any methods to do this, so
could someone pls help if there is an easy function/code to do this? thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm working on an exact solution, but basically, you should use javascript `JSON.parse` to convert the json to a javascript object. Then you can change it to fit how you want it. If you want to convert it back into json just use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` for that. Read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: your wanted object is invalid since you cannot have keys on array elements. Perhaps the inner array `[]` should be converted to an object `{}`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, It's okay to have keys in an array as they are automatically converted into objects.

Comment: I just noticed that the first JSON object you showed wasn't valid, as it had a trailing comma. Is this on accident?

Comment: Obligatory reminder that JSON is a *string*, there's **no such thing as a JSON object!**. I have removed the JSON tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build new entries and create objects.

```js
var data = { headings: ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], rows: [[{ a: "abc", b: "def" }, "value1", "value2", "value3"], [{ a: "abc", b: "def" }, "value1", "value2", "value3"]] },
    rows = data.rows.map(a => Object.fromEntries(data.headings.map((k, i) => [k, a[i]])));

console.log({ rows });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With lodash's

- [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) for mapping,
- [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fromPairs), for getting objects and
- [`_.zip`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip) for transposing arrays.

```js
var data = { headings: ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], rows: [[{ a: "abc", b: "def" }, "value1", "value2", "value3"], [{ a: "abc", b: "def" }, "value1", "value2", "value3"]] },
    rows = _.map(data.rows, a => _.fromPairs(_.zip(data.headings, a)));

console.log({ rows });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To change the JSON object, you can easily convert it to a javascript object by using `JSON.parse("the JSON object")`.

After that, make changes to your object with javascript.

If you want to convert it back into JSON, use `JSON.stringify(javascriptObject)`.

In your case, you'd want to do something like this:

```js
function reformat(jsonString) {
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var headings = data.headings;
    var rows = data.rows;

    var reformattedData = {
        rows: []
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        reformattedData.rows[i] = {};
        var currentRow = reformattedData.rows[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
            currentRow[headings[j]] = rows[i][j];
        }
    }
    return reformattedData;
}

console.log(reformat(String.raw`
{
    "headings": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            {
                "a": "abc",
                "b": "def"
            },
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3"

        ],
        [
            {
                "a": "abc",
                "b": "def"
            },
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3"
        ]
    ]
}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Destructuring

```
let obj = {
    "headings": [ "col1",  "col2",  "col3", "col4",
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            {   "a": "abc",  "b": "def", }, "value11","value12","value13"
        ],
        [
            {   "d": "ghi",  "e": "jkl", }, "value21","value22","value23"
        ],
    ]
} ;

for(let i = 0 ; i < obj.rows.length ; i++){


    let{ ...temp} = obj.rows[i] ;     //    gives  { '0' : {.....} , '1' : "value11" , '2' : "value12" , '3'  : "value13" }
    // console.log("temp ==> " ,temp) ;
    let count = 0 ;
    obj.headings.map(el => {
        temp[el] = temp[count]       // we just replace the keys in temp object with values in headings array :)
        delete temp[count++] ;
    });
    obj.rows[i] = temp ;
}

console.log(obj.rows) ;
```